# Strange behaviour using `sed`

Tags: linux, bash, sed, formatting

So, I'm trying to remove tabs after the numbers in this table I'm formatting from the command line. Below is the original table data, coipied and pasted directly from the file in question:

```
File Path                   Line  Description
/home/nick/.bashrc             9         # TODO        Chop this into code import files
/home/nick/.bashrc           204         # TODO        Add $HOME/os-setup to OS installation disc
/home/nick/.bashrc           207         # TODO        Custom power actions don't work; system tray notifications
```

When adding a final `sed` command to the pipe however, some strange behaviour occurs. As an example, consider the `sed` command below:

```
cat somefile.txt | column -tx -s : | sed -e 's/\([0-9]\{1,\}\)/\1/g'
File Path                   Line  Description
/home/nick/.bashrc             9         # TODO        Chop this into code import files
/home/nick/.bashrc           204         # TODO        Add $HOME/os-setup to OS installation disc
/home/nick/.bashrc           207         # TODO        Custom power actions don't work; system tray notifications
```

This finds the numbers in each row of the table, then replaces the match with the first part of the regular expression. As the whole match is wrapped in braces, this means that nothing changes as it's replaced by itself.

However, when I then try the same `sed` command, but I add the `\t` character, a literal tab, to the matching regex the `sed` output seems to truncate the number match also! See below:

```
cat somefile.txt | column -tx -s : | sed -e 's/\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\t/\1/g'
File Path                   Line  Description
/home/nick/.bashrc               # TODO        Chop this into code import files
/home/nick/.bashrc           20  # TODO        Add $HOME/os-setup to OS installation disc
/home/nick/.bashrc           20  # TODO        Custom power actions don't work; system tray notifications
```

Why does `sed` truncate the last digit from each number? How can I stop `sed` from doing this?

Comment: could you please show the sed code with the \t?

Comment: interesting, can't reproduce it

Comment: @NickBull : Where did the file come from?

Comment: @sjsam It's not really a file per se, but the output from a grep command on a text file from a very large bash script I'm helping to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of  removing the tab after the number I am removing the spaces before the `# TODO`.

**awk(GNU) solution**

```
awk '{print gensub(/[ ]+(  # TODO)/,"\\1","g",$0)} ' file
```

**sed solution**

```
sed -E 's/[ ]+# TODO/  # TODO/' file
```

**Output**

```
File Path                   Line  Description
/home/nick/.bashrc             9  # TODO        Chop this into code import files
/home/nick/.bashrc           204  # TODO        Add $HOME/os-setup to OS installation disc
/home/nick/.bashrc           207  # TODO        Custom power actions don't work; system tray notification
```

**Assumption**

The description always begin with a `# TODO`

**Note**

You may put desired number of spaces before the `# TODO` in selection. I put two.